# PnP continues Webjob does not execute to provision the site collection

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have deployed a sample of PnP partner pack to Azure storage and two webjobs are created. One scheduled and the other continuous.

I created a couple of site collections via the UI "create site collection page" and when I check the PnPProvisioningJobs library in the provisioning site collection, the job status show "pending". However the WebJob status show "running".

the json setting file contains the following settings:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "ContinousJob",
  "startTime": null,
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": null,
  "interval": null,
  "runMode": "Continuous"
}
```

Any idea how can I configure this to run continuously as now apparently is not doing that.

And the Scheduled WebJob has these settings:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "ScheduledJob",
  "runMode": "OnDemand"
}
```

Could you please show me how can I set it to run on schedule every 2 hours, for example?

Answer (score 1):

> the job status show "pending". However the WebJob status show "running".
>
> Any idea how can I configure this to run continuously as now apparently is not doing that.

If the web job status shows pending restart , it means that the job fails to start usually (an exception?). You could look in the jobs dashboard for logs. Also, make sure that  your code is correct.

And according to the above code, it seems that you haven’t passed values to these properties. That  would cause green wavy lines warning.  You could refer to the following code to pass values. It works fine on my side.

```html
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "WebJobContinuous1",
  "startTime": "2018-02-14T06:45:24.3473721Z",
  "endTime": "2018-02-14T07:45:24.3473721Z",
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute",
  "interval": 5,
  "runMode": "Continuous"
}
```

> Could you please show me how can I set it to run on schedule every 2 hours, for example?

You could create a **settings.job** file at the root of your WebJob .zip file to achieve your goal.

After you published your local **schedule web job** to Azure, you could see files in Kudu.
For example , Azure portal>Web App>Advanced Tool>Click **Go**(KuDu)>choose Debug console CMD>**site>wwwroot>App_Data>jobs>triggered>open your web job>create a file named settings.job.**

In **settings.job** file, add the following code to add CRON expression.

```html
{
    "schedule": "0 0 */2 * * *" 
        
}
```

The settings.job file in web job in KuDu:
[image]

After you **refreshed** the web job status in Web App>Web Jobs, you could see the schedule property has changed.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs).

> You can enter the CRON expression in the portal or include a settings.job file at the root of your WebJob .zip file, as in the following example:

```html
{
    "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *"
}
```

Comment: Hi Janley, have tried your settings but I can't seem to get it working and I don't see the same thing as you show in the print screen. To me it still shows "Schedule": n/a.

Comment: 1.Publish your schedule web job to Azure App Service first. The default status is "Schedule: n/a"(If you haven't published it) 2.Please make sure you have created a settings.job file in Web Job folder in Kudu. 3. Add the CRON expression code in settings.job file to change the schedule. 4. Refresh the Web job status in App Service>Web jobs. Or you could refresh the Azure pages(F5).Finally, check the schedule status again.

Comment: This is my gif result:https://image.ibb.co/cP03Hn/webjobg2.gif. If you still have not solved it yet, you could tell me what you have tried. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have not had much time to focus on this issue as I had to work on something else. I will try to get back to you with more info as soon as possible. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I am having a problem with the Azure storage as my free subscription has expired. I am trying to use a separate azure storage account and a different office365 tenant. but I am having problems setting it up. Any idea how to set this up? Hosting files in a azure storage account that is different with Office 365 tenant account?

Comment: It seems to be a new question. Why don't create a new thread for this issue? I'm glad to help you. This thread just shows how to set schedule for trigger webjobs.

Comment: If the web job works fine, you could mark as answer to close this thread. Then you could post a new thread for your storage account problem. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: I just posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295107/setting-up-azure-active-directory-found-in-a-different-office-365-tenant-account

Comment: I can't mark it as answered yet as I am trying to set up my azure storage first and then I can try it there the webjob